# How to automatically update JSON data without page refresh using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a google sheet where stock data is being updated every 3 minutes. I have a page where I can see the data in html table. but that data is not changing automatically. I have to refresh the page or I have to set meta `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">` to refresh the page periodically.

> I want **the data coming from JSON must have to be updated automatically** without the
> page refresh. here is my code.

**JSON Object Link**

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx.json
```

**Div to show json data**

```
<div id="json">json here</div>
```

**Javascript to fetch and show json data**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(47).slice(0, -2))  
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    table += '<tr>'
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
        try{var valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v}
        catch(e){var valeur = ''}
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      }
    )
    table += '</tr>'
    }
  )
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
</script>
```

I know one js library kickout js, but i am unable to implement and get desired result using kickout js. so how I can achieve a table which updates JSON data automatically without page refresh ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you try `setInterval`?

Comment: i am getting "1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present."

`setInterval(fetch, 5000);
fetch(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch new data periodically using setInterval and update your table rows. You can assign a unique ID to each row and update them in your function that runs periodically.

```
setInterval(function() {
    // fetch data here and update rows.
}, 180000);
```